# Join Predicates And Comparison Operators

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In an attempt to better understand how SQL joins work, I've run into difficulty understanding the result set returned from a query -- The tables I'm using are:

Employees

```
Id  Name    Salary  Gender  City
1   Sam     2500    Male    London
5   Todd    3100    Male    Toronto
3   John    4500    Male    New York
6   Jack    7000    Male    Shangri La
4   Sara    5500    Female  Tokyo
2   Pam     6500    Female  Sydney
```

and Gender:

```
ID  Gender
1   Male
2   Female
3   Unknown
```

The first query returns all the columns from an inner join on the Gender column -

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Gender
ON Employees.Gender = Gender.Gender
```

The returned result -

```
Id  Name    Salary  Gender  City        ID  Gender
1   Sam     2500    Male    London      1   Male
5   Todd    3100    Male    Toronto     1   Male
3   John    4500    Male    New York    1   Male
6   Jack    7000    Male    Shangri La  1   Male
4   Sara    5500    Female  Tokyo       2   Female
2   Pam     6500    Female  Sydney      2   Female
```

Which is pretty much what I expected. However when I changed the comparison operator -

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Gender
ON Employees.Gender != Gender.Gender
```

What I originally thought would return an empty set, returned this -

```
Id  Name    Salary  Gender  City        ID  Gender
4   Sara    5500    Female  Tokyo       1   Male
2   Pam     6500    Female  Sydney      1   Male
1   Sam     2500    Male    London      2   Female
5   Todd    3100    Male    Toronto     2   Female
3   John    4500    Male    New York    2   Female
6   Jack    7000    Male    Shangri La  2   Female
1   Sam     2500    Male    London      3   Unknown
5   Todd    3100    Male    Toronto     3   Unknown
3   John    4500    Male    New York    3   Unknown
6   Jack    7000    Male    Shangri La  3   Unknown
4   Sara    5500    Female  Tokyo       3   Unknown
2   Pam     6500    Female  Sydney      3   Unknown
```

While I can ***kinda*** see how the not-equals(!=) operator would return this result it begs the question of what type of comparisons are useful in join predicates and which aren't - does the type of join [inner, right, left...] impact the returned result adversely or can the join type and comparison be resolved to actionable behavior(in other words does it always have to be ==)? Also if there are any sources out there that could help me, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner join is a subset of the Cartesian product of both tables.  That is, every row in one table is paired with every row of the other table.

So, if one table has n rows and the other m rows, then the Cartesian product has n * m rows.

The `on` clause filters these rows.  Equality is the most common filter and such joins are often called equi-joins.  They are offer the most optimization opportunities and are typically the most efficient.

(Outer joins are similar but have a mechanism to include unmatched rows.)

Normally, `join` predicates contain at least one equality comparison (although this is not necessary).  Other comparisons -- including subqueries using `exists`/`in` -- are allowed and often useful.

Any decent documentation or tutorial or book should be able to explain this.

In your case, often `not exists` is the intention.  To find employees whose gender is not in the reference table:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Gender g WHERE e.Gender = g.Gender)
```

Of course, such a query would be unnecessary if you used the primary key to reference the table and included proper foreign key declarations.

Comment: Thanks!! Could you elaborate a little more on outer joins since that will be the focus of my endeavors next? Also a relevant text or article or keywords I can use in a search. Thanks ever so much.